# Replace any string after the last dot with txt string

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, perl

how to replace any string after the last "." to txt

for example

```
filter.bash
sum.sh
portG.py
run.doK.ksh
```

expected results

```
filter.txt
sum.txt
portG.txt
run.doK.txt
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^.]*$/txt/'
```

Or to do it only for lines that contain at least one `.` (not change `myfile` to `txt`):

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$/.txt/'
```

To also avoid replacing `.bashrc` with `.txt`:

```
sed 's/\(..*\.\).*/\1txt/'
```

(this time, we rely on the greediness of `.*` to replace the part after the *last* `.`).

To also avoid replacing `foo.d/myfile` with `foo.txt`:

```
sed 's|\([^/]\.\)[^./]*$|\1txt|'
```

To also add a `.txt` extension to files that don't have any extension (including changing `.bashrc` to `.bashrc.txt` but not touching empty lines nor lines ending in `/`):

```
sed 's|\([^/]\)\.[^./]*$|\1|;s|[^/]$|&.txt|'
```